# How can i display view specific content type based on dynamic term name in node page?

Tags: 7, views

Hi i have a content type called "**Resource**" with 2 term reference fields, **branches (A,B,C,D)** other one is  **resource category (rec cat 1,rec cat 2)** ,and i have created view called **branches list** displayed all branches like below in one node page.

```
A
B
C
D
```

and i have created another view called **resources list** it contains info based on resource category term reference it's ok but i need to display this view items based dynamic branch term name in my node page like when i click **A** need to display related branch info in my node page.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource list view should accept the branch as ***contextual filter***. Have a look here: [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)

Maybe also consider using [quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) for showing these views.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay @remy i have created contextual filter from your provided url in resource list view section but no results getting "no query run" error in views section make sure i have checked related vocabulary.

Comment: you need to provide a contextual filter for the preview, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/no-query-was-run-when-contextual-filter-is-added-was-working-before

Comment: Thanks saved my time it's working , in contextual filter section i have choose Provide default value type is PHP Code see https://www.drupal.org/node/1871388